# Javascript spread operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to get these properties from an object using es6 directly on the parameters list of the function but I don't know how to do it exactly:

```
    function methodA(person){
       var driverName = person.name,
       age = person.age,
       company = person.job.company;
       ...
    }
```

Any tips in that direction?

Comment: For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Basic_assignment

Answer (score 1):

Take a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
function methodA(person) {
    var { name: driverName, age, job: { company } } = person;
    console.log(driverName, age, company);
}

methodA({ name: 'Grace', age: 49, job: { company: 'Infinity' } })
```